# How to detect login device from a validation rule?

Tags: validation-rule

I need to detect whether user logged from salesforce1 or desktop from salesforce validation rule? Is it possible to get from a validation rule?

Comment: Why you wanna restrict yourself to Validation rules anyways? Validation rules are present to validation form input before server-submit. It hardly makes any sense to use them in your requirement.

Comment: Hi Prasad, its not possible.

Comment: Hi Mahmood, thanks for the reply. Our requirement is to restrict salesforce1 users who is creating opportunities above stage3. Therefore we need to write a validation rule for that and needs to detect whether the user is salesforce1 user or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some 7 years passed after your question, but just got into similar scenario.

In my case, I used the $UIThemeDisplayed global variable, which gives you the theme that user is rendering. Open the following link for more information:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm